# android c2dm Unknown permission com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES

Tags: android, android-c2dm

```
WARN/ActivityManager(157): Unable to start service Intent {
 act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf  (has extras) }: not found 
 02-08 13:19:11.376:WARN/PackageManager(157): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH in package com.google.android.gm 
 02-08 13:19:11.376: WARN/PackageManager(157): Unknown permission com.google.android.googleapps.permission.GOOGLE_AUTH.mail in package com.google.android.gm         
 02-08 13:19:11.376:WARN/PackageManager(157):Unknown permission com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES in package com.google.android.gm
 02-08 13:19:11.376:WARN/PackageManager(157):Unknown permission com.google.android.voicesearch.AUDIO_FILE_ACCESS in package com.google.android.gm 
 02-08 13:19:11.376:WARN/PackageManager(157): Unknown permission com.estrongs.android.pop.PERMISSION in package com.estrongs.android.pop
 02-08 13:19:11.376:WARN/PackageManager(157): Unknown permission adroid.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in package com.***.***
 02-08 13:19:11.376:WARN/PackageManager(157): Unknown permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
```

---

I have the problem only in the real Device(HTC uv880  Android2.2).
can you help me resolve the problem? thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICS, these permissions are related to Google and other third-party applications, so you do not need to worry about them.

Basically, each application is free to define its own permission for certain intents, so it is quite natural that the PackageManager cannot know all of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but my application which uses C2DM service run normally in the AVD but in the real Device it has logs as follows :Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gsf (has extras) }: not found....can you help me with this problem??